# Set an object with Immutability-Helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I'm trying to update State with Immutability-Helper and React but I don't have result expected.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        parents: {}
    };
}

handleParent = (member, data) => {
    // ex : member = 'applicant'
    // ex : data = {'gender': 'man', 'pseudo': 'Tom'}
    let newParent = update(this.state.parents, {
        [member]: { $set: [data]}
    });

    this.setState({'parents': newParent});
};
```

Result :

```
parents {
    'applicant': {
        0 : {'gender': 'man', 'pseudo': 'Tom'}
    },
    'partner': {
        0 : {'gender': 'woman', 'pseudo': 'Julie'}
    }
}
```

But I would like parents to be :

```
parents {
    'applicant': {
        'gender': 'man',
        'pseudo': 'Tom'
    },
    'applicant': {
        'gender': 'woman',
        'pseudo': 'Julie'
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you assigned `$set: [data]` which on run-time will evaluate to `$set:[{'gender': 'woman', 'pseudo': 'Julie'}]` for instance, meaning, a single value array.
Just remove the square brackets and your'e good to go:

```
let newParent = update(this.state.parents, {
    [member]: { $set: data }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @MorKadosh ! ;)